# Permission of installed electron application

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, deb

I created an electron application that has a sqlite database with it. After creating a .deb installer and installing it into my raspberry pi, i'm getting some permission errors, the application is logging that the database is read only. I tried running the app with sudo `sudo ./appname --no-sandbox` and it worked, but am I really suppose to do that? why does it have no permission on its folder `/usr/lib/appname`.

Also, i'm using `app.getAppPath("userData") + "/database.db"` to get the path to the database.